# HazelCast Member with/without Client is ok for standalone web application

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast

I am new to caching mechanism and just started learning about Hazelcast. I gone through couple of tutorials and hazelcast site but still I am not clear.

I am trying to build a caching for my springboot & angular application. It is a single standalone application.

So in my case, since my application single and no plan in running as multiple instance can I just go with Hazelcast member without client. Is client is needed?

Answer (score 1):

No, the client is not mandatory, and for your case it would seem unnecessary.

The idea is around abstraction, you ask Hazelcast for item *X* and it is returned if it exists. Hazelcast works out where that item is held, and **mostly** this is hidden from you.

*X* could be found in your process:

- Your process is a client, has *near-caching* active, and has a copy.
- Your process is one of 1 or more servers, and happens to be the server responsible for storing item *X*.

*X* could be found in another process:

- Your process is a client, has no *near-caching*, so is not storing anything
- Your process is one of several servers, and it happens that one of the other servers is responsible for item *X*.

"Mostly this is hidden from you" == There will be a retrieval time difference between data found in the same process and data retrieved from another process, as it has to pass across the network. If this is a significant difference at low volumes, it's time to upgrade the network.